# How to use multiple GPUs effectively when training deep networks?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, multi-gpu

I am using a machine which has 2 GPUs Titan Black to train my deep learning model which has 3 layers (3x3, 3x3 and 5x5).

The training runs pretty well but when I watch nvidia-smi (watch every 1 sec), I realized that my program uses only one GPU for computation, the second one always 0% even when the first one reach 100%.

I am trying to use *tf.device* to assign specific tasks for each of them but then they run one-by-one, not in parallel, and the total time was even increased, not reduced (I guess because 2 GPUs had to exchange values with each other)

Below is my program. It is quite messy, maybe you just need to pay attention at the graph where I use **tf.device** is enough...

Thank you so much!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from os import listdir, sys
from os.path import isfile, join

from time import gmtime, strftime
import time

def validatePath(path):
    path = path.replace("\\","/")
    if (path[len(path)-1] != "/"):
        path = path + "/"
    return path

hidden_size_default = np.array([16, 32, 64, 32])
cnn1_default = 3
cnn2_default = 3
cnn3_default = 5

SIZE_BATCH_VALID = 200

input_path = 'ARCHIVES-sub-dataset'

output_path = 'ARCHIVES-model'

log_address = "trainlog.txt"

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('h0', hidden_size_default[0], 'Size of hidden layer 0th')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('h1', hidden_size_default[1], 'Size of hidden layer 1st')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('h2', hidden_size_default[2], 'Size of hidden layer 2nd')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('h3', hidden_size_default[3], 'Size of hidden layer 3rd')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('k1', cnn1_default , 'Size of kernel 1st')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('k2', cnn2_default , 'Size of kernel 2nd')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('k3', cnn3_default , 'Size of kernel 3rd')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('input_path', input_path, 'The parent directory which contains 2 directories: dataset and label')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', output_path, 'The directory which will store models (you have to create)')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('log_address', log_address, 'The file name which will store the log')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

load_path = FLAGS.input_path
save_model_path = FLAGS.output_path

log_addr = FLAGS.log_address

load_path = validatePath(load_path)
save_model_path = validatePath(save_model_path)

cnn1 = FLAGS.k1
cnn2 = FLAGS.k2
cnn3 = FLAGS.k3

hidden_size = np.array([FLAGS.h0, FLAGS.h1, FLAGS.h2, FLAGS.h3])

# Shuffle the dataset and its label
def randomize(dataset, labels):
    permutation = np.random.permutation(labels.shape[0])
    shuffled_dataset = dataset[permutation,:]
    shuffled_labels = labels[permutation]
    return shuffled_dataset, shuffled_labels


def writemyfile(mystring):
    with open(log_addr, "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(str(mystring + "\n"))

num_labels = 5

def accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))/ predictions.shape[0])

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def DivideSets(input_set):
    length_set = input_set.shape[0]
    index_70 = int(length_set*0.7)
    index_90 = int(length_set*0.9)

    set_train = input_set[0:index_70]
    set_valid = input_set[index_70:index_90]
    set_test = input_set[index_90:length_set]
    return np.float32(set_train), np.float32(set_valid), np.float32(set_test)

# from 1-value labels to 5 values of (0 and 1)
def LabelReconstruct(label_set):
    label_set = label_set.astype(int)
    new_label_set = np.zeros(shape=(len(label_set),num_labels))
    for i in range(len(label_set)):
        new_label_set[i][label_set[i]] = 1
    return new_label_set.astype(int)

def LoadDataSet(load_path):
    list_data = [f for f in listdir(load_path + "dataset/") if isfile(join(load_path + "dataset/", f))]
    list_label = [f for f in listdir(load_path + "label/") if isfile(join(load_path + "dataset/", f))]
    if list_data.sort() == list_label.sort():    
        return list_data
    else:
        print("data and labels are not suitable")
        return 0

# load, randomize, normalize images and reconstruct labels
def PrepareData(*arg):
    filename = arg[0]
    loaded_dataset = pickle.load( open( load_path + "dataset/" + filename, "rb" ))
    loaded_labels = pickle.load( open( load_path + "label/" +  filename, "rb" ))
    if len(arg) == 1:
        datasize = len(loaded_labels)
    elif len(arg) == 2:
        datasize = int(arg[1])
    else:
        print("not more than 2 arguments please!")
    dataset_full,labels_full = randomize(loaded_dataset[0:datasize], loaded_labels[0:datasize])
    return NormalizeData(dataset_full), LabelReconstruct(labels_full)

def NormalizeData(dataset):
    dataset = dataset - (dataset.mean())
    dataset = dataset / (dataset.std())
    return dataset

### LOAD DATA
listfiles = LoadDataSet(load_path)

# divide
listfiles_train = listfiles[0:15]
listfiles_valid = listfiles[15:25]
listfiles_test = listfiles[25:len(listfiles)]


graphCNN = tf.Graph()

with graphCNN.as_default():
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):

        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 224,224,3)) # X
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_labels)) # Y_

        dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        if dropout == 1.0:
            keep_prob = tf.constant([0.2, 0.3, 0.5], dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            keep_prob = tf.constant([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], dtype=tf.float32)

        weights_1 = weight_variable([cnn1,cnn1,3, hidden_size[0]])
        biases_1 = bias_variable([hidden_size[0]])
        weights_2 = weight_variable([cnn2,cnn2,hidden_size[0], hidden_size[1]])
        biases_2 = bias_variable([hidden_size[1]])
        weights_3 = weight_variable([cnn3,cnn3,hidden_size[1], hidden_size[2]])
        biases_3 = bias_variable([hidden_size[2]])
        weights_4 = weight_variable([56 * 56 * hidden_size[2], hidden_size[3]])
        biases_4 = bias_variable([hidden_size[3]])
        weights_5 = weight_variable([hidden_size[3], num_labels])
        biases_5 = bias_variable([num_labels])

        def model(data):
            with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
                train_hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(data, weights_1) + biases_1)
                train_hidden_2 = max_pool_2x2(tf.nn.relu(conv2d(train_hidden_1, weights_2) + biases_2))
                train_hidden_2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(train_hidden_2, keep_prob[0])

                train_hidden_3 = max_pool_2x2(tf.nn.relu(conv2d(train_hidden_2_drop, weights_3) + biases_3))
                train_hidden_3_drop = tf.nn.dropout(train_hidden_3, keep_prob[1])
                train_hidden_3_drop = tf.reshape(train_hidden_3_drop,[-1, 56 * 56 * hidden_size[2]])

                train_hidden_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(train_hidden_3_drop, weights_4) + biases_4)
                train_hidden_4_drop = tf.nn.dropout(train_hidden_4, keep_prob[2])

                logits = tf.matmul(train_hidden_4_drop, weights_5) + biases_5
            return logits

        t_train_labels = tf.argmax(y_, 1)   # From one-hot (one and zeros) vectors to values    
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model(x), labels=t_train_labels))

        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

        y = tf.nn.softmax(model(x))

### RUNNING

print("log address: %s" % (log_addr))

#num_steps = 10001
times_repeat = 20 # number of epochs
batch_size = 100

with tf.Session(graph=graphCNN,config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=0)

    writemyfile("---ARCHIVES_M1----")
    mytime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    writemyfile(str("\nTime: %s \nLayers: %d,%d,%d \epochs: %d"  % (mytime,cnn1,cnn2,cnn3,times_repeat)))

    writemyfile("Train files:" + str(listfiles_train))
    writemyfile("Valid files:" + str(listfiles_valid))
    writemyfile("Test files:" + str(listfiles_test))

    print("Model will be saved in file: %s" % save_model_path)
    writemyfile(str("Model will be saved in file: %s" % save_model_path))

    ### TRAINING & VALIDATION
    valid_accuracies_epochs = np.array([])
    for time_repeat in range(times_repeat):
        print("- time_repeat:",time_repeat)
        writemyfile("- time_repeat:"+str(time_repeat))

        for file_train in listfiles_train:
            file_train_id = int(file_train[0:len(file_train)-4])

            time_start_this_file = time.time()

            #LOAD DATA
            print("- - file:",file_train_id, end=' ')
            writemyfile("- - file:" + str(file_train_id))

            Data_train, Label_train= PrepareData(file_train)

            for step in range(0,len(Data_train)-batch_size,batch_size):
                batch_data = Data_train[step:step+batch_size]
                batch_labels = Label_train[step:step+batch_size]
                feed_dict = {x : batch_data, y_ : batch_labels, dropout: 1.0}
                opti, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, y], feed_dict=feed_dict)

            train_accuracies = np.array([])
            for index_tr_accu in range(0,len(Data_train)-SIZE_BATCH_VALID,SIZE_BATCH_VALID):
                current_predictions = y.eval(feed_dict={x: Data_train[index_tr_accu:index_tr_accu+SIZE_BATCH_VALID],dropout: 0.0})
                current_accuracy = accuracy(current_predictions, Label_train[index_tr_accu:index_tr_accu+SIZE_BATCH_VALID])
                train_accuracies = np.r_[train_accuracies,current_accuracy]

            train_accuracy = train_accuracies.mean()                    
            print("batch accu: %.2f%%" %(train_accuracy),end=" | ")
            writemyfile("batch accu: %.2f%%" %(train_accuracy))

            time_done_this_file = time.time() - time_start_this_file
            print("time: %.2fs" % (time_done_this_file))
            writemyfile("time: %.2fs" % (time_done_this_file))

        # save model
        model_addr = save_model_path + "model335" + "-epoch-" + str(time_repeat) + ".ckpt"
        save_path = saver.save(session, model_addr,) # max_to_keep default was 5

        mytime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        print("epoch finished at %s \n model address: %s" % (mytime,model_addr))
        writemyfile("epoch finished at %s \n model address: %s" % (mytime,model_addr))

        # validation
        valid_accuracies = np.array([])
        for file_valid in listfiles_valid:
            file_valid_id = int(file_valid[0:len(file_valid)-4])
            Data_valid, Label_valid = PrepareData(file_valid)
            for index_vl_accu in range(0,len(Data_valid)-SIZE_BATCH_VALID,SIZE_BATCH_VALID):
                current_predictions = y.eval(feed_dict={x: Data_valid[index_vl_accu:index_vl_accu+SIZE_BATCH_VALID],dropout: 0.0})
                current_accuracy = accuracy(current_predictions, Label_valid[index_vl_accu:index_vl_accu+SIZE_BATCH_VALID])
                valid_accuracies = np.r_[valid_accuracies,current_accuracy]

        valid_accuracy = valid_accuracies.mean()
        print("epoch %d - valid accu: %.2f%%" %(time_repeat,valid_accuracy))
        writemyfile("epoch %d - valid accu: %.2f%%" %(time_repeat,valid_accuracy))

        valid_accuracies_epochs = np.hstack([valid_accuracies_epochs,valid_accuracy])

print('Done!!')
writemyfile(str('Done!!'))
session.close()
```

**Update:** I found [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) seems to be a good example for training with multi GPUs, but honestly I don't know how to apply on my case.

Comment: are both your GPU's used when running cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py?

Comment: I tried running it but got error when the model is imported: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.models'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
def model(data):
    with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
```

to:

```
def model(data):
    for d in ['/gpu:0', '/gpu:1']:
        with tf.device(d):
```

and ditch the line `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`

Since at the first `with tf.device...` you are only doing initiation
of variables and then you are resetting your devices with the next `with tf.device`.

Let me know if this works since I can't test it.

Comment: Thank you @Anton, I tried that one when I read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus) but  only the first GPU works.

Comment: sorry, it's actually both GPU are running now. I did not realized, but the time it took for training a batch is still the same to when it using 1 GPU.

Comment: You could try using keras which is an abstraction on top of tensorflow. It's what I prefer to use and the code is a lot more concise than tensorflow's. Using multiple GPU's is quite easy in Keras, just use the script mentioned [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2436) by jonilaserson

Comment: Thank you @Anton, I will give it a try!